# Sending http request in javascript causes error

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```
function callApi(url){
    debugger;

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
    oReq.open("GET", url);
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 3Zx7SfvX4zsvbiGhvW4hAA..');
    oReq.send();

    //buildPage(xhr.responseText, mainDiv);
}
```

Gives error --Refused to connect to 'http://dummysite/psupadmin/v1/contexthelp/mypayslip/25/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".

calling this webservice from https://dummysite

Notice the request is calling http and not https

```
callApi("https://dummysite/psupadmin/v1/contexthelp/mypayslip/25");
```

function call above

Answer (score 0):

This is what [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) says:

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy response header allows web site
>   administrators to control resources the user agent is allowed to load
>   for a given page. With a few exceptions, policies mostly involve
>   specifying server origins and script endpoints. This helps guard
>   against cross-site scripting attacks (XSS).

I think it explains pretty much everything.

`connect-src:self` is an HTTP directive in the webserver configuration that means that the webserver doesn't answer to cross-site queries (JavaScript client-side queries coming from other domain names).

If it is your webserver then you can easily change that value, if it is not, then you can't do much about it as it is a security feature made on purpose by the server administrators.

Comment: Well my problem is really is that content-src is self, but its sending a http request instead of a https request, even tho I am calling this api https://dummysite/psupadmin/v1/contexthelp/mypayslip/25

Comment: the api call is https